# typescript typings, whats the typings folder

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, definitelytyped

I am trying to wrap my head around typings and have the following questions

1. What is the typings folder that you find under the node_modules root folder of the project.  Is this the default place tsc looks for .d.ts files and how do I use them in the source files.
2. Some of the node_modules contains the .d.ts files in them.  Does tsc look in here by default again?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. When you install typings with `npm install @types/my-favorite-library`, they are inserted by default into the @types/ folder. This is the default place for TypeScript to search for definition files.
2. Yep, so long as you have `"moduleResolution": "node",` in your tsconfig.json file. This is the default value unless you have your "module" set to "amd", "System" or "ES2015".

Comment: What is the typings.d.ts file, is this obsolete since by default typescript will look at particular folders based on what is said in the tsconfig.json?

Comment: @user3547774 I can't promise that it's obsolete, but I haven't had to use typings.d.ts since TypeScript 2.0, so it probably is.

Comment: Check the typescript official *modules resolution* documentation. At this time, it extends the node module resolution algorithm just a bit by including the file you set in package.json => "types": "dist/index.d.ts" option (and this is just an example).